# How do I refer to a foreign key variable in JPQL using the @Query annotation in Spring Boot?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, jpql

This is the Query in my repository interface.

```
@Query("SELECT new com.wellsfargo.loanManagementSystem.model.LoanCardAndEmpCardProjection"
        + "(l.loanId,l.loanType,l.durationInYears," 
        + "e.cardIssueDate)"
        + "FROM LoanCardMaster l JOIN l.loanEmpCardDetails e where e.employeeId = :employeeId")
```

And this is how I am refering to employeeId right below.

```
List<LoanCardAndEmpCardProjection> findSelectedFieldsFromLoanAndEmpCards(@Param("employeeId") String employeeId);
```

EmployeeId is a foreign key for where loanEmpCardDetails is from (EmployeeCardDetails Table). Am I referring to emploeeId incorrectly in my query or in the function below because when I execute it as a query in WorkBench I am getting the right result.

```
select
l1_0.loan_id,l1_0.loan_type,l1_0.duration_in_years,l2_0.card_issue_date
from loan_card_master l1_0 join employee_card_details l2_0 on
l1_0.loan_id=l2_0.loan_id_loan_id where
l2_0.employee_id_employee_id=1;
```

The `LoanCardAndEmpCardProjection` model class

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class LoanCardAndEmpCardProjection {
    
    private String loanId;
    private String loanType;
    private Integer durationInYears;
    private LocalDate cardIssueDate;
}
```

And this is LoanCardController, when I execute I get status 500, internal server error.

```
@GetMapping("/getEmpLoanData/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<List<LoanCardAndEmpCardProjection>> getLoanInfo(@PathVariable String  id) {
    try {
        List<LoanCardAndEmpCardProjection> selectedFields = loanCardService.getLoanInfo(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(selectedFields);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(null);
    }
}
```

Also, when I run the GET request in Postman without the @PathVariable annotation, I get this in my console. So I assume employeeId isn't being passed properly.

```
Hibernate: select l1_0.loan_id,l1_0.loan_type,l1_0.duration_in_years,l2_0.card_issue_date from loan_card_master l1_0 join employee_card_details l2_0 on l1_0.loan_id=l2_0.loan_id_loan_id where l2_0.employee_id_employee_id=?
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you get when you execute the code? Empty result or some exception?

Comment: are you getting an error when executing the code? it would be nice to share the interface `LoanCardAndEmpCardProjection`, I am suspecting the order of the fields in the interface is different or the method names are different.

Comment: The order seems to be the same in the LoanCardAndEmpCardProjection class

Comment: I have added the controller in the edits. I seem to be getting an internal server error when I give the @PathVariable annotation. Without the annotation I get an empty result.

Comment: What is the exception when you get 500?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the id is of type Long, so try to change this

```
List<LoanCardAndEmpCardProjection> findSelectedFieldsFromLoanAndEmpCards(@Param("employeeId") Long employeeId);
```

Comment: It is of type String in the class where it is defined as well.

Comment: But in your example, where you provided sql which you run directly against DB, it is a number "l2_0.employee_id_employee_id=1"

Comment: Yeah, not sure why the query works